# How to use Math.max.apply on an array containing arrays

Tags: javascript

I have the following js functions:

```
function Weekday (name, traffic) {
this.name = name;
this.traffic = traffic;
}

function mostDays(){
var traffic=[];
traffic[0] = new Weekday('monday',6);
traffic[1] = new Weekday('tuesday',5);
return traffic;
}

function mostPopularDays(week) {    
if(week.length == 0 || week === null) return null;

return Math.max.apply(Math, week['traffic']);
}
```

so if I say:

```
 var x = mostDays();
 var test = mostPopularDays(x);
```

I'm trying to get back 6 which is the max value of traffic amongst the Weekday objects .  Is there a way to reference this correctly or do I need to do all this in a loop?

Comment: Try `Math.max.apply(Math, week.map(day => day.traffic))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the wanted property of the object and get then the max value.

```js
function Weekday(name, traffic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}

function mostDays() {
    var traffic = [];
    traffic[0] = new Weekday('monday', 6);
    traffic[1] = new Weekday('tuesday', 5);
    return traffic;
}

function mostPopularDays(week) {
    if (!week.length) return null;
    return Math.max.apply(Math, week.map(function (o) { return o.traffic; }));
}

var x = mostDays();
var test = mostPopularDays(x);

console.log(test);
```

With ES6, you could spread the values for `Math.max`.

```js
function Weekday(name, traffic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}

function mostDays() {
    return [
        new Weekday('monday', 6),
        new Weekday('tuesday', 5)
    ];
}

function mostPopularDays(week) {
    if (!week.length) return null;
    return Math.max(...week.map(o => o.traffic));
}

var x = mostDays();
var test = mostPopularDays(x);

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the day for which traffic is the most then `Math.max` cannot do it on its own, as it will just return the highest traffic (if you code it right), but not the day.

You could use `find` to do the lookup of the day with the highest traffic:

```
var maxTraffic = Math.max(...week.map(day => day.traffic));
return week.find(day => day.traffic === maxTraffic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be to specify the default [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf#Examples) of the object:

```js
function Weekday(name, traffic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}
Weekday.prototype.valueOf = function() { return this.traffic }

var days = [ new Weekday('monday', 6), new Weekday('tuesday', 5) ]

console.log( Math.max.apply(0, days) )
console.log( Math.max(...days) )
```

---

Otherwise, [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Getting_the_maximum_element_of_an_array) can be used:

```js
function Weekday(name, traffic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}

var days = [ new Weekday('monday', 6), new Weekday('tuesday', 5) ]

var max = days.reduce((m, d) => Math.max(m, d.traffic), 0)

console.log(max )
```